# Android: Added Buttons into Scrollview do not have the right size

Tags: android, button, dynamic, scrollview

In an Activity I have added a horizontal Scrollview. This contains an "Add new Set" button and all previously added Sets as buttons. These Sets a saved in a SQLLite Database.

In the beginning of my App I load all Sets from the database. For each Set I add an own Button into the scrollview.

All buttons are shown, but the dynamically added buttons don’t have the right size. They should have the same height and width as the “Add new Set” button.

How I can copy the dimensions of the first button to the others?

Here my XML:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/innerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_NewSet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:height="100dp"
            android:onClick="OnExitClick"
            android:text="@string/New_Set"
            android:width="100dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Here my Java-Code:

```
 db.open();
 Cursor allSets = db.getAllSets();
 if (allSets.moveToFirst())
 {
    Button bDummy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_NewSet);
    LinearLayout innerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.innerLayout);
    do 
    {
          Button b1 = new Button(this);
          b1.setHeight(bDummy.getHeight());
          b1.setWidth(bDummy.getWidth());
          b1.setText(allSets.getString(1));
          b1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
              ));                   
          innerLayout.addView(b1);

    }while (allSets.moveToNext());
 }
 db.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not the same size because the dynamic buttons also use wrap_content. If you want them the same size you can use the width and height property of the button "id/btn_NewSet" in the layoutparams of the new buttons

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer, but still have a little “problem”.  
I have changed my code to:
`b1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(bDummy.getWidth(),              bDummy.getHeight()));`
Every time I try to access the width and height of the button "id/btn_NewSet" it is “0”. This code was first located in “onCreate”, but even if is located in “onPostResume” the dimensions of the first button are “0”.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using dynamic view inflation:

1) make a dedicated xml (mybutton.xml, for instance):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/btn_NewSet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:height="100dp"
        android:text="@string/New_Set"
        android:width="100dp" />
```

2) Inflate and attach it to `innerLayout` dynamically:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout innerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.innerLayout);
    do 
    {
        Button b1 = (Button)inflater.inflate(R.layout.mybutton,null);
        b1.setText(allSets.getString(1));
        innerLayout.addView(b1);
    }while (allSets.moveToNext());
```